# Replace extension using basename in one line of code

Tags: linux

In bash linux

```
v1=$(basename $0)           gives filename.ext

v1=${v1%.*}.log             replaces ext  filename.log
```

how to combine in one line? When I try below I get bad substitution error

```
v1={($(basename $0))%.*}.log
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use parameter expansion on parameters, so in general you can't do this.

However, in this specific case you can reorder the operations since it doesn't matter whether you basename or strip extension first:

```
v1=$(basename "${0%.*}.log")
```